# Add a bottom border to UITableView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I would like to add a bottom border to my table view in swift, which will act as a separator. I tried the answers to some other questions, but most of them included `CGRectMake`, which is now outdated. Any thoughts?

Here is the code I am using, which doesn't produce an error message, but doesn't work:

```
let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: tableView.frame.size.height - width, width:  tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    tableView.layer.addSublayer(border)
    tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can use：CGRect(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)

Comment: @ChildrenGreens I have tried that, but that doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: You can look at the key code?

Comment: @ChildrenGreens I'm not sure what that means... I'm very new at this...

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong. You can show some of the error code?

Comment: please copy your code snippet and edit the post and add the code (format it as code). and also copy the error messages you get from the code

Comment: @EricPhillips Can you show us what do youwant actually ? any design ?

Comment: you can use footerview

Comment: like tblSettings.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tblSettings.frame.size.width, 1)];